# Unity 3D: void OnMouseDown() isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onmousedown

So, in Unity3d, when I use this following script below, the console does not say the message given by the Debug.Log. Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Gui : MonoBehaviour
{

   void OnMouseDown()
   {
       Debug.Log("It Works");
   }
}
```

However, when I click on the object that includes this script, nothing shows up on the console. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try following these instructions:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/486847/onmousedown-doesnt-work-1.html

Comment: Just a thing: the instruction with debug.log has no semicolon at the end. Is it a copy&paste error from your C# file? It should not compile this way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, `OnMouseDown` works on GUI elements or objects with colliders. Add a collider to your object and it should work fine.

[Unity OnMouseDown()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)